# Is it possible to wrap css subclasses under a single class?

Tags: css

Is it possible to wrap multiple subclasses somehow, e.g. `html-wrapper` style:

```
.class{
    .subclass1{
        /* rules */
    }
    .subclass2{
        /* rules */
    }
}
```

as opposed to:

```
.class .subclass1{
    /* rules */
}
.class .subclass2{
    /* rules */
}
```

It would make editing various elements on a single page much easier than constantly referring to the parent page/`div`, in the same way that `@media{}`does. Is this currently achievable?

Comment: With a CSS pre-processor, yes. http://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus

Comment: SCSS, LESS or similar other pre processor languages support this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in pure CSS. However you can do this in CSS pre-processor, for instance Sass. You can read more about it [here](http://sass-lang.com/)